# Selecting Data through Typed Search and Displaying this in same Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and I have a searchbox (input type="text") where u type the name and number of the contact ur looking for in the table.

What I want to achieve is that this typed selection's results will be indicated/shown in the same table!

What I want to know is how do I Identify the selection that has been typed so I can work it out in a 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE' function so I can then add this variable to make sql search it for me in the table.

Normally I use a config.php page to make the sql and this will then display results on a new page, but this time I want the results to be indicated in the same table on the same page!

Is this possible?

My searchbox model:

```
<legend>Voer het Naam en Nummer in dat je wilt opzoeken</legend>

<input type="text"  id="Naam" name="Naam" placeholder="Voer een Naam in" /><br/> 
<input type="text"  id="Nummer" name="Nummer" placeholder="Voer een Nummer in" /><br/>
```

My Table:

```
<?php

    include("pagination.php"); 

        if(isset($res))
        {
            //creating table
            echo '<table style="width:1500px; cell-padding:4px; cell-spacing:0; margin:auto;">';       
            echo'<th>id</th><th>Time</th><th>Answered Y/N</th></th><th>Naam</th><th>Caller ID</th>'; 

           while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
              echo '<tr>';

              echo '<td>'.$result['callapiid'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['statusCalling'].'</td>';
              if ($result['statusAnswered'] =="NULL"||$result['statusAnswered'] =="Null" || $result['statusAnswered'] =="null" || $result['statusAnswered'] =="")
      {
      echo "<td>Not Answered!</td>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "<td>Answered!</td>";
      }
              echo '<td>'.$result['calleridname'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$result['calleridnum'].'</td>' ;
              echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
    ?>
```

& $res variable in pagination.php :

```
<?php


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  // select database
  mysql_select_db("voizxl_wachtrij", $con); ////provide database name

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Callflow");
 $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

 $base_url = 'https://localhost/pagi/';
  $per_page = 50;                           //number of results to shown per page 
  $num_links = 8;                           // how many links you want to show
  $total_rows = $total_rows; 
  $cur_page = 1;                           // set default current page to 1

if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
      $cur_page = $_GET['page'];
      $cur_page = ($cur_page < 1)? 1 : $cur_page;            //if page no. in url is less then 1 or -ve
    }

  $offset = ($cur_page-1)*$per_page;                //setting offset

  $pages = ceil($total_rows/$per_page);              // no of page to be created    

 $start = (($cur_page - $num_links) > 0) ? ($cur_page - ($num_links - 1)) : 1;
    $end   = (($cur_page + $num_links) < $pages) ? ($cur_page + $num_links) : $pages;

 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Callflow LIMIT ".$per_page." OFFSET ".$offset);

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

I would appreciate ur help and advice thank you in advanced!

An example: http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: where is the declaration for `$res` variable...?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want? It's not clear to me from the question.

Comment: It's on my pagination Page, I shall edit and add it

Comment: mysql is not SQL Server

Comment: Now would be a good time to abandon deprecated methods. Also, in the absence of an ORDER BY clause LIMIT and OFFSET are meaningless.

Comment: My script is working perfectly, tho thnx for the advice! I just wanna know how to ID the typed search to work it out in a SELECT * FROM function